# Instagram - Joint IG Live - Audio Codec

Tags: audio, instagram, audio-streaming, codec, instagram-story

I'm trying to find out which Audio / Video codec is switched to when somebody else JOINS your IG Live (collaborative IG Live). As opposed to the higher-quality codec for a standard IG Live.

I am working with a LOT of musicians who - during Coronavirus lockdown - want to be able to interviews interspersed with music on collaborative IGLives

But the voice-optimised, low-latency audio codec that gets switched in when someone joins your IG Live completely prohibits this. Obviously works great for speech but is absolute pants with music.

I realise the codec used is chosen for performance for the 2way low-latency conversation, but I wonder if the communication codec be different to the Outgoing broadcast audio codec at all? Or any way to increase the quality of Music broadcast during a 'joint' IG live.

Thanks

Comment: It's probably not just the codec, but echo cancellation and noise suppression.  These algorithms absolutely wreck audio quality for music... making it unusable.  They're everywhere because they "come for free" with the WebRTC stack, and most folks want to enable voice communication without having to use headphones.  I can't speak to Instagram, but for any web-based situation, I've worked up a browser extension that can disable echo cancellation and what not.  It's currently going through review, but drop me an e-mail to brad@audiopump.co and I'll add you to the beta group if you want.